# При использовании консольного приложения QT не открывается сама консоль

Tags: c++, qt, консоль

Гуглил, искал, у многих проблема заключалась в том, что у .pro файла не было строки

```
CONFIG += c++11 console
```

но у меня она есть...
У меня стоит винда и убунта рядом, проблема на обоих ОС та же. Уже хз что делать. Если код просто что-то виводит, то результат есть в окне вывода, но вот если надо ввести какие-нибудь данные, то приходит проблема. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Создайте консольный проэкт через мастер, и там сравните конфигурацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Галку поставьте:

[image: Галку поставьте]

Она переключает открытие терминала или вывод в окно вывода.